# Generating authentication token for APNS connection

Tags: java, jwt, vert.x

I am new to vertx, and using an app server created via vertx for connection with APNS for push notifications.

I created an authProvider via

```
private JWTAuth createOauthProvider() {
   PubSecKeyOptions pubSecKeyOptions = new PubSecKeyOptions()
   .setAlgorithm("ES256").setSecretKey(*/private key from .p8 extracted as is removing unwanted part in base64*/);
   return JWTAuth.create(vertx(), new JWTAuthOptions().addPubSecKey(pubSecKeyOptions));
}
```

and then a JWT via

```
private String createJwt() {
   Instant now = Instant.now();
   JsonObject decoded = new JsonObject()
   .put("alg", "ES256")
   .put("kid", "kid here")
   .put("iss", "teamid here")
   .put("iat", now.getEpochSecond());
   String jwt = oauth2JWTProvider.generateToken(decoded,
   new JWTOptions().setAlgorithm("ES256"));
   return jwt;
}
```

Now here's my query -

1. Is my token creation criteria correct?
2. JWT created after this when send to APNS returns a 403-InvalidProviderToken.

Appreciate all the help i can get. Thanks!!

Comment: The APN documentation says "Unsecured JWTs, or JWTs signed with other algorithms, are rejected, and your provider receives the InvalidProviderToken (403) response". so it may be possible that the secret you are using not correct, or there may be issue in it. Also make sure you are using the correct team ID and key ID.  
 
 https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW1.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question as i was able to get around this and just in case it helps anyone else. Just posting the createJwt() method rest everything remains same-

```
private String createJwt() {
            Instant now = Instant.now();
            JsonObject header = new JsonObject()
                    .put(JwtConstants.ALG, "ES256")
                    .put(JwtConstants.KID, "kid here");
            JsonObject payload = new JsonObject()
                    .put(JwtConstants.ISS, "team id here")
                    .put(JwtConstants.IAT, now.getEpochSecond());
            String jwt = oauth2JWTProvider.generateToken(payload,
                    new JWTOptions()
                            .setHeader(header)
                            .setAlgorithm("ES256"));
            return jwt;
        }
```